# Laravel != operator in where not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

This query is returning null when an object is expected.

```
$vow = DB::table('media_featured')->where('is_video_of_the_week', 1)->
where('video_of_week_expired', '!=', 1)->first();

CREATE TABLE `media_featured` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`media_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`is_video_of_the_week` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_featured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`video_of_week_expired` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`featured_expired` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `media_featured_media_id_foreign` (`media_id`),
CONSTRAINT `media_featured_media_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `media`        (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

A record might have `is_video_of_the_week = 1` and `video_of_week_expired = NULL` but the above query returns null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NULL` values are not equal or not equal to anything else.

So `column != NULL` is always falsy as well as `column = NULL`

To check if a column contains `NULL` value you need to use `IS NULL` operator.

In case of laravel db query generator you could use

```
->whereNull('video_of_week_expired')
```

method.

PS: if `video_of_week_expired` is assumed to be a flag-alike column, you better make it `NOT NULL` and use `0`/`1` values, instead of `NULL`/`1`

Comment: The above did work for me before I posted to SO. I'm planning on flagging the column as is_expired = 1 once it's no longer featured, that's why I wanted to compare against not =1 as opposed to whereNull, but I guess I will just have to be careful in my code execution?

Answer (score 8):

If the value for `video_of_week_expired` is `NULL` or `1` then you can use

> ->whereNull()

else
if the value is like a flag `0` or `1` then you can try using

> ->where('video_of_week_expired', '<>', 1)

Here `<>` is a 'not equal to' operator.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) and the [source-code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e62812948af83d57976985601ed67a1a0ee93fff/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L749).

You should use `whereNull`:

```
$vow = DB::table('media_featured')
          ->where('is_video_of_the_week', 1)
          ->whereNull('video_of_week_expired')
          ->first();
```