# I want to get data from my database excluding some part of my data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
     if($city!='Others'){

            $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->where(['city'=>$city])->paginate(10);
    }
    else{
            $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->whereNotIn(['city'=>'Lahore'])->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

I have displayed some specific data now I want to display 
data other than those which were displayed before.

First if is showing normal data and I am trying to display remaining data in else part.

Comment: `whereNotIn('Lahore')` ?!? Shouldn't there be a column name here for a column that may contain the value `'Lahore'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help. The only thing required was to keep whereNotIn statement values in an array. Like this.

```
    if($city!='Others'){

            $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->where(['city'=>$city])->paginate(10);
    }
    else{
   $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->whereNotIn(['city',array('Lahore')->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WhereNotIn` will take `array` of value You also need to pass column name in it

```
if($city !='Others'){
    $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->where(['city'=>$city])->paginate(10);
}
else{
    $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->whereNotIn('city',['Lahore'])->paginate(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess based on how your database is setup.

**EDIT based on reply (see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses and [Laravel != operator in where not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260171/laravel-operator-in-where-not-working)):**

```
if($company!='Others'){
        $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->where(['company'=>$company])->paginate(10);
        }
        else{
            $posts = Post::orderby('id','desc')->where('city', '<>', 'Lahore')->paginate(10);
        }
```

Does that help (take a look at the links)?

Comment: Yes it is a guess I want to know which function should called in place of 'whereNotIn'